# The labelline of piechart of apache echart is visible on hover

Tags: angular, pie-chart, echarts, apache-echarts

I'm having trouble hiding the label line on hover in my pie chart using ECharts. I've successfully hidden the label and label line initially with ECharts options, but the label line remains visible when hovering over pie chart
The sample code for hiding the label and label line is

```
chartData = [
{ value: 20, name: 'Open', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } },
{ value: 30, name: 'In Progress', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } },
{ value: 60, name: 'Done', label: { show: false }, labelLine: { show: false } }];
```

[image]

Comment: `label: {show: false}` seems to be enough to hide labels + line. See [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5CPkwDRUU4CGAJhACuRWEwCsABgCkHLugA2PAEZZ5xJBgAWwAO7EAZj3nYAvp2ro-PMD2JkLFJLABuRwY1gBGCQBYAHOyw0DwAth5MAMpYPDgAxpqwAKLQAOYQ0FhMsGZyji5uHgDsAMxigcFhzAAiEDhYsWBZOQ7oTq7y7sRifhLloeGJITwQ8k3mLW0FxP4-fZWiAKrQUHAAgnwYY7mt-R0exRK9Qf3MAGoQfFjAsOub2bkAuuPoJuQPKCYA3EA). If its not working for you, pls share your full chart option.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the basic implementation to hide label line:

[EXAMPLE:](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQBKOAZjgE5OzB2wCGsA6jgEYBnCGByUANEXQCArnxHkqAMQ4BrHLAAiHMB3GTYuOhViUAxjmgjGlIgF8J6MMGBZIIAqmIZGEAOa-mKmEcAFsbdHsiXADoABMPfWAfC2NKADcmSFMOLD0vQ1SC8NhIqSYIHAECAG19Ty9YaA4Q_BMAQVNzAQFYRUZgMIcGsABPEFbKEAq8hsYOWIhpKpMAVgAGAFIZr1jtDhr9LyRYNJzpVoBGNYAWAA4xRuaJgGUcDkZTAAtYAFFoXwg0FEJSGDWQJzOrQA7ABmFYPJotKgaCDMUxgSggw7EY6nLDnAgrW5rBFPKg_EIcCC5LFg9C4yEEO7XUlIkwAVWgUDgbViAkxpTpDPxrRhaxJjzZlAAahBYjhgLBefyStiALqg4hYDh8HBYBJ0hoCT7AADuBDAjHOmsNdCSlLAVgIACIkLFbBtnQ8APTe5B8WywZggZgCFI9RE4B5IUyB4Oh8MQkXId1BnAhyqJ8YfFLYsEgYBCSAwF2AoTyr2wX2wACawGksGycHmACslmAMJ91AWi9zWOwwF2DDq9QI8w07ZZnhAAF6XEnYwVeUIgT4cITLepg4IhZ6jXAGw2wY3zM0AIXxjAIVxtRrXsTNAHk6HQw2AABoEBdH4_3s0AYRcJIqEYXw-A4AAKCVoIeNYADoVgASmKMFbEXfQ0PQNUUFsABuIA)

You can do `show:false` to hide label as well.

```
label: {
   show: false,
}
```